# How to add a logout feature to an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, authentication, logout, tabbar

I've an app with this layout:

When you open the app you see a login screen. You log in and you see a tabbar with 3 tabs. (The loginview is displayed with a presentModalView in the appdelegate of tabbar).

In the third tab there is a logout button. I want when logout button is pressed the app delete NSUserDefaults and shows the loginview again. And if you login again the login screen disappear and you see the first tab of the tabbar.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do as follows,

1. Place your login view in first view controller.
2. Place your tabbar controller in second view controller.
3. Store the second viewcontroller instance in appDelegate (this will be used for navigation).
4. Now when the logout button is pressed,use the stored instance navigate your view.

Comment: Ok, you're saying to change my layout and not use modalpopup but a nav controller, right? Loginview is the firstview --> tabbar is the secondview.

Comment: @kingoofbliss: there is a way to change the transition effect when you switch from a first view to a second view? I mean the standard default effect for a navigation controller, when you push a view.

Comment: @joaquin: check core animation

Comment: do you know one examples for what I want? Thanks again.

Comment: u want to change the animation of the transition from one view to another view right?

Comment: If so, do as follows. Before the following code [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
add this line, vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

Comment: is not pushViewController? why presentModalViewController is I use a NavigationControlller? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @KingofBliss Hi, If you are using presentModelViewController to present the tabbarcontroller then it will be simple to use [self dissmissModelViewController];</break>if you have presented model view controller over your login screen then you will be able to show that login screen back after calling dissmissmodelviewcontroller method on self.