# Switch from TabBarView back to Standard View

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have implemeneted an application where you login, and once you log in it brings you to a tab bar view. However, I want to implement a log out button where when the user pushes the button it brings them back to the login view.

I have the following code right now, but it dosn't work. The UIBarButton is being invoked, because its producing NSLog output to gdb. However it dosn't switch the views.

In my view for the tab bar.

```
- (IBAction) logoutButtonPushed {
    NSLog(@"Yes, I was pushed");
    [self.appdelegate logout];
}
```

Then in my app delegate.

```
//  Logout and return to the welcome view
- (void) logout {


    [self.tabBarViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [window addSubview:self.welcomeViewController.view];
    [window bringSubviewToFront:self.welcomeViewController.view];

    [userModel logout];
}
```

Just for kicks, here is how I bring the tab bar to the front.

```
//  Switches to the tab bar view from either the welcome or registersuccess view
- (void) switchToTabBarView {

    [self.registerSuccessViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.welcomeViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [window addSubview:self.tabBarViewController.view];
    [window bringSubviewToFront:self.tabBarViewController.view];

}
```

Any help, or suggestions to improve my code (I probably have many a bad practice) would be welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to my answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320946/iphone-app-logout/4321060#4321060).

You should not use `self`, because it won't refer to the tabbar controller. Instead of `self`, use the instance of the view controller where you placed your tabbar controller

In `AppDelegate.h`

```
YourViewController *yourViewControllerObj;
@property(nonatomic,retain) YourViewController *yourViewControllerObj;
```

In `AppDelegate.m`

```
@synthesize yourViewControllerObj;
```

In `YourViewController.m`, set object for your `AppDelegate` instance:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    appDelegate.yourViewControllerObj = self;
    // Do whatever you want
}
```

then in your logout function

```
- (IBAction) logoutButtonPushed {
  NSLog(@"Yes, I was pushed");
  loginScreen *loginScreenObj = [[loginScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"loginScreen" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
  [appDelegate.yourViewControllerObj  presentModalViewController:loginScreenObj animated:YES];
  [loginScreenObj release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for expanding on this!

Comment: So how would I bring the tab bar to the front in the first place?

Comment: in maincontroller use only login viewcontroller.. in another viewcontroller place the tabbarcontroller..