# Regarding Login Page before loading Tabbarcontroller with navigationcontroller for iPhone

Tags: iphone

As i am newbie i want to add navigation controller with tabbar controller and login page and when i click on logout button on tabbar controller view it will let me to login page without navigationbar as well as without tabbar contrller.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320946/iphone-app-logout/4321060#4321060).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on click of that tab call a function and that function contains these line of code

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;//for hiding tabBar
```

befor push statements

and use this

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;//for hiding navigation bar
```